# MVC Core - What is the difference between UseIIS and UseIISIntegration

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Looking at the codes, they have the same comments, suggesting that they do the same thing:

```
/// <summary>
/// Configures the port and base path the server should listen on when 
/// running behind AspNetCoreModule. The app will also be configured 
/// to capture startup errors.
/// </summary>
```

`UseIIS` is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS` package, while `UseIISIntegration` is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration`.

What is the difference between the two? When do you need to use one versus the other? (or maybe both?)

**UPDATE:** There is a similar question on github, But there is no helpful answer there: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6197

Comment: Why is your question worded almost identically to [this one on github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6197)?

Comment: See edit history

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Before ASP.NET Core 2.2, ASP.NET Core was hosted out-of-process in IIS, meaning we had two processes for an application:

1. `w3wp.exe`, the IIS process; and
2. `dotnet.exe`, the ASP.NET Core process, where the Kestrel web server was started.

This means that IIS and Kestrel were communicating between those two processes.

For this scenario, you would use `UseIISIntegration`.

---

ASP.NET Core 2.2 introduced in-process hosting, where your ASP.NET Core app is ran inside of the IIS `w3wp.exe` process, removing the need for the Kestrel web server, in which case you want to use `UseIIS`.

Notes:

- the official documentation seems to indicate that the `CreateDefaultBuilder` method will call the appropriate method by itself; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-the-iisintegration-components
- Rick Strahl has some nice diagrams to show the differences between out-of-process and in-process hosting in the following blog post: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22

Comment: Your answer is incomplete

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I mistyped and submitted before I was done ‍♂️

Comment: So we don't need to call UseIIS for in process hosting?

Comment: thanks Michkael for sharing reference link of Rick's blog that is really informative

Comment: Excellent article thanks for sharing. Kudos to Rick as well

Answer (score 1):

Refer the blog from "Rick Strahl" with cool mind and you will find it very easy.

for the differences between out-of-process and in-process hosting in his [blog post here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22)

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22

Comment: This answer does not cover the question, the blog does not discuss 'UseIISIntegration'