# Intermitted .NET 6 web application crash using Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, kestrel-http-server

I have a .NET 6 web application that crashes intermittently when using Kestrel:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|5_0(SocketError e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|5_0(SocketError e)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Warning: Connection processing ended abnormally.
```

I can't reliably cause it to happen, but it always happens eventually, usually after 5-20 mins of running. The web app stalls completely, and this is the last message we can get out of any logging.

This looks like some kind of socket connection error, but it happens on local machines, it happens with VSCode or VS2022 debuggers attached.

This entire stack points to Microsoft code, no part of it points to the code in our app.

Any idea where to start fixing this? What might be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this was a footgun buried in .NET for anyone upgrading from .NET Core to modern .NET

We found that `dotnet.exe` and `w3wp.exe` were creating hundreds of IPv4 Loopback connections. Eventually they'd run out and we'd get this crash.

Early versions of Kestrel didn't run within IIS - instead IIS would run a proxy and pass connections on to Kestrel (more in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673395/mvc-core-what-is-the-difference-between-useiis-and-useiisintegration)). This proxy had a fairly severe bug - cancellation tokens would cause IIS to close the connection and move on, but IIS wouldn't tell Kestrel and it would just keep running.

Every time a cancellation token happened `w3wp.exe` would cancel the loopback connection, but `dotnet.exe` would keep doing whatever slow thing it was working on. Meanwhile things would get slower for our users (more of a queue) so they'd navigate away, cancelling yet another request and making the queue worse.

But we're on .NET7 now, it should be running in process, right?

Firstly, we were still using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` (the .NET Core method) instead of the `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` (the new one since .NET6) in our start up - the older Core method defaults to Kestrel running out of process.

So we [fixed that up](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/0e0372c3c1d895c3ce195ba983b1e03d) and it *still* happened.

We'd missed that `web.config` has a setting here too:

```xml
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

This caused Kestrel to still run out of process and crash whenever too many navigation cancellations happened.

The final fix was:

```xml
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

Once we'd done all of that it was finally fixed and stopped happening. If you find yourself here with the same problem debug your code and check the current process name (`Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName`) - if it's `w3wp.exe` great, you're running in IIS, but if you are using IIS and you get `dotnet.exe`  instead that means it's fallen back to out of process mode and (if you use cancellation tokens) you could see the same connection pool related crashes.