# HTTP Error 500.32 - ANCM Failed to Load dll

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-7.0, azure-appservice

I have upgraded a .NET Core 2.1 web app to .NET 7.

The application works fine on Visual Studio 2022.

When I deploy that to Azure through Azure DevOps pipelines, I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.32 - ANCM Failed to Load dll
> Common solutions to this issue:
> The application was likely published for a different bitness than w3wp.exe/iisexpress.exe is running as.
> Troubleshooting steps:
> Check the system event log for error messages
> Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
> Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
> For more information visit: https://{this site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/detectors and https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526

If I just add the following line to the project file, it works fine on Azure

```
     <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

I understood from experts that InProcess is better performing than OutofProcess and therefore would like to fix the issue with InProcess.

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <AssemblyName>ABC.Web</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>ABC.Web</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>2d8de5d0-adb3-41a5-90a7-299d114b1dda</UserSecretsId>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Staging</Configurations>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="node_modules;jspm_packages" />
    <Content Remove="web.config" />
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\staging.pubxml" />
      <None Include="App.config" />
      <None Include="web.config" />
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;**.cshtml;Views\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ABC.ApplicationServices.Core\ABC.ApplicationServices.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ABC.Common.Core\ABC.Common.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ABC.Data.Core\ABC.Data.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ABC.Domain.Core\ABC.Domain.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Elmah.Io.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.56" />
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus.Core" Version="1.5.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="EvoHtmlToPdf_NetCore_Client" Version="7.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="PDF.Core" Version="2020.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web" Version="1.0.0-beta0009" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Views\EmailTemplates\ReleasedEmail.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\PDFTemplates\ReportTemplates\SubmissionSummary.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\PDFTemplates\ReportTemplates\STSubmissionSummary.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\PDFTemplates\ScheduleRunSheet.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\Shared\ArchivedAModal.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\Shared\Archived.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\Shared\ExpiredLink.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\EmailTemplates\RequestCancellation.cshtml">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Views\EmailTemplates\RequestChanged.cshtml">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Home\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\app.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\ABC.Web.dll.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\web.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\appsettings.json" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\appsettings.Production.json" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\appsettings.Staging.json" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\ABC.Web.deps.json" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="PUBLISH\ABC.Web.runtimeconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Not sure how I can attached the file. I have added it as a code snippet to my original question

Comment: When you deploy the app, web.config file will be created in the `site\wwwroot` directory.Change the value of `stdoutlogEnabled ` to true and run the app.Detailed error will be created in a file in logfiles folder.

Comment: I changed that value in the web.config of the project but the generated web.config had stdoutLogEnabled="false". Looks like I dont have control over this web.config file that is autogenerated. 
I could not edit this file in Kudu and I got this error:

ERROR

409 Conflict: Could not write to local resource 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config' due to error 'Access to the path is denied.'.

Comment: If possible can you share your code repo?

Comment: How does your `program.cs` and `Startup.cs` files look?

Comment: To access the web.config file add an appsetting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` with value 1 as mentioned in this [doc](https://dotnetthoughts.net/azure-app-service-kudu-409-conflict/)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Harshitha. I did try that, but nothing was being written to the log after that. I will try again will update the outcome here.

Comment: Where you are checking the log.A new file will be generated in logfiles section..are you checking in the same file?

Comment: After editing the web.config has the following line

<aspNetCore processPath=".\Showcast.Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled=
"true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />

Where would .\logs\stdout be located? I could not find this in C:\home\site\wwwroot>

Comment: My question has been closed unfortunately. Not sure why though...

Comment: You can check logs at `C:\home\Logfiles` folder

Comment: I resolved the issue by following suggestions on
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673395/mvc-core-what-is-the-difference-between-useiis-and-useiisintegration

changed 

.UseIISIntegration()

to 

.UseIIS()

Program.cs

Comment: What was the error

Comment: Application '/LM/W3SVC/1564594207/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
Managed server didn't initialize after 120000 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by following suggestions on

[MVC Core - What is the difference between UseIIS and UseIISIntegration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673395/mvc-core-what-is-the-difference-between-useiis-and-useiisintegration)

changed

.UseIISIntegration()

to

.UseIIS()

Program.cs