# IIS shutting down my application, returns 503 service unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, iis, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to host an API I've done in dotnet core, very standard stuff, acceses and returns data from a Database. I've deployed to IIS before (not in this machine) and it usually goes all right, but not this time.

I've created the WebApp on IIS, launched WACS to create and assign a certificate to it, and ran it, all good, the DNS is pointed correctly and I can retrieved some data from the APIs, however, a few requests later I get this:

**The service is unavailable.**

Well, that's odd, the application is able to work perfectly fine in Kestrel where I just execute it and the cmd windows popups saying it's hosting the app, but as soon as I move it to IIS all hell breaks loose and after a few retries it seems to fail.

I've checked the Event Viewer and this is what's happening:

[image]

Ok great, the App seems to have been started successfully.

A few moments later this happens:

[image]

Wait what? Why is IIS trying to shutdown the application? It works just fine when running the exe in Kestrel-only mode.

What I've done:

I've gone to the settings and changed these:

[image]

I've disabled Rapid-Fail protection in fear that it would be some execeptions that are turning it off.

Doesn't seem to be it... It still dies after a few requests.

I've added this user to the folder's permissions:

[image]

And this is the only app running on this IIS machine:
[image]

And the test connection is telling me this:

[image]

Could this be the issue? If it is why would it be able to serve a few requests and then try to shut itself down?

Can anyone help me? I've never has an issue where IIS is trying to shutdown its own applications.

PS: The Application logs tell me that it's just shutting down:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\IIS Root\RVGL API\
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

And the IIS logs just show me the requests, it's serving a couple of 200s and then just 503s.

This is my Program.cs, I don't know if it matters:

```
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };

            });

            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "RVGL Endpoints",
                    Version = "v1"
                });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "",
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
            });
            var app = builder.Build();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors(builder => builder
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
            );

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/test/swagger.json", "test API");
                c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SubmitMethod[] { });
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.MapControllers();
            app.Run();
```

it seems like Kestrel runs fine and has no issue, but as soon as it's hosted on IIS it seems to turn crash the application, App Pool seems ok, I've also tried hosting it on a different machine with different OS (Windows Server 2022) and the same issue happens, I've also tried hosting it on another Windows 11 machine, exact same issue.

Comment: Do you have something like Sentry attached to this giving you real time crash events? Maybe something is being obscured or being captured where it doesn't make its way into event viewer.

Comment: did you configure your application to use IIS integration aka `UseIISIntegration` at `WebHostBuilder` ?

Comment: @iSR5 I did, the application is using             builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration();

Comment: @2189490 I installed Sentry and all it did was tell me the Event Log was saying the application failed to gracefully shutdown.

Comment: Often IIS issues are due to TLS failing.  IIS does not support the latest encryption methods used by TLS 1.3.  The TLS certificate contains an encryption mode that may not be supported on IIS. You need to verify the encryption mode in the certificate and then check if it is supported in IIS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @jdweng even when I'm just using HTTP without any Certificate it dies after a few requests.

Comment: Does it every connect?  You said it fails after a few retries.  Not clear if it ever works.  Did you check the even viewer for errors?

Comment: @jdweng It connects and the API is able to send a few requests, perfectly just like in dev, but after around 5 or so requests it shuts down the API, the event viewer just says "Failed to gracefully shutdown"

Comment: Is there anything in the Application log in the Windows Event Viewer

Comment: Please try using FRT to view details about the 503 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @Charlieface the only thing that would be related to this would be The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history directory 'C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000082'.  The directory will be skipped and ignored.  Note that the directory may still get deleted in the future if the service restarts.  The data field contains the error number.

Comment: did you install the hosting bundle? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

Comment: See if there is any useful entry in the Windows event logs at the time of shutdown.

Comment: @david-ao yes I installed the latest bundle that was available and I'm running dotnet 6

Comment: When the server hangs, crashes or performance is low, 
it is usually necessary to grab the server's thread stack (Thread Dump) for subsequent analysis. Maybe the Debug Diagnostics Tool can be a lifesaver, it creates and analyze IIS crash dumps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/parvez/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag. But analyzing dump files is a complex process, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, 
there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.

Comment: can u put your code in somehting like git hub ? 
myabe there is background service or something operating system relevant , or 
share the launcheSettings with us

Comment: Check:
1. options for disabling the application due to idle time in IIS are disabled.
2.  all autorun and prestart options enabled.

Comment: I don't see your IIS integration settings.
IIS for interaction with an application that is hosted outside the process at startup specifies a random port on which it will redirect all requests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderiisextensions.useiisintegration?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @RedNet set your application pool `StartMode` to `Always Running`, and in your site advanced settings set `Preload Enabled` to `true`. check if this will solve it.

Comment: Are you running the application pool under an account with the correct privileges?

Comment: @Nikolay adding             builder.WebHost.UseIIS().UseIISIntegration(); did nothing :(

Comment: @AHoughton this also happens when using the IIS express in visual studio.

Comment: @RedNet Use one, not both at once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673395/mvc-core-what-is-the-difference-between-useiis-and-useiisintegration

Comment: Don't use IIS. It is shittiest reverse-proxy-service-manager-all-in-one-application ever. Hangs without explanation, restarts on a whim, etc. Just run kestrel and start some custom reverse-proxy such as nginx in docker/k8s. Over my experience with IIS it is always some woodoo involved to figuring out wtf is it even doing.

Comment: @eocron ain't that the truth brother

Comment: Do you have Web.config in the dir?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least following points to be verified:

1. Certificate IO Stream has been disposed;
2. External libraries / unhandled OOP communication has been covered with logging behavior

Similar to any other webservers check resources usage.
The program file looks lightweight and the bug somewhether in sight.

**If running of a program succeed expected result all the time using MS VS IDE,it will be good tip for you to restart application and attach debugger directly to IIS's application process**
[image]